# complexity of generating a sparse matrix

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a symmetric matrix S(n*n) where approximately 70% of the data are 0.

Symmetric matrix

[image]

I want to convert the symmetric matrix into a sparse matrix with t rows.

What would be the time complexity of generating a sparse matrix from the original symmetric matrix?

Is it O(n^2), because I have to go through every row/column intersection and get the elements that are not 0?

Since I am dealing with a symmetric matrix, can I can say that my time complexity could reduce to O((n*(n+1))/2) because in symmetric matrix a[i][j]= a[j][i]? In this case I could say a[j][i]=0 if I encounter a[i][j] as 0. This could reduce my loops by approximately half.

Comment: Why would it not be `O(n^2)`? In the full matrix you have no information about what elements are non-zero, so you still have to iterate over more than half the elements.

Comment: Please post your analysis. Your update seems to be saying "I'm not sure if it's `O(n^2)` because I have to go through `O(n^2)` elements".

Comment: @ Beaker,  Ya I am not very good at computing cost, Since I am dealing with a symmetric matrix can I say that my time complexity could reduce to O((n*(n+1))/2). because in symmetric matrix a[i][j]= a[j][i], so I could say a[j][i]=0 if I encounter a[i][j] as 0.

Comment: "This could reduce my loops by approximately half" - `C*n^2 == O(n^2)` for any constant `C`, including one half.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When converting from a full representation of a symmetric matrix to a sparse representation, you will need to scan all the elements on the main diagonal and above (or symmetrically on the main diagonal and below). For an (n x n) matrix matrix this is (n^2+n)/2 entries that need to be scanned. Therefore you need to perform O(n^2) work just to determine what needs to be inputted into the sparse matrix.

When constructing the sparse matrix, you will need to store all the non-empty entries in the original matrix into your sparse matrix. For a 0 matrix this requires no additional work and for a fully dense matrix this requires (n^2+n)/2 insertion operations.

Therefore converting from a symmetric matrix to a sparse representation will always take O(n^2) time -- in fact it takes Theta(n^2) time.

Comment: gotcha thanks Josilber.  However I have another question related to time complexity of sparse matrix. I would like to have some insights on that from you ..  please find it here:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873805/computing-time-complexity-of-the-sparse-matrix-2